# BST implementation java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, data-structures

I studied C++ , but I am quite new to Java.I am trying to write a binary search tree(BST) class.Here is my code:

```
public class binary_tree {
     public class node 
    {
        int data;
        node left , right;
        node(int data , node left , node right)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }
     private node root = null;
     public void addElement(int x)
     {
         addElementNotSeen(x , this.root);
         //this function allows the user to only give x
         //as a parameter

     }
     private void addElementNotSeen(int x , node curent)
     {
         if (curent == null)
         {
             curent = new node(x , null , null);
         }
         else
         {
             if (x > curent.data)addElementNotSeen(x , curent.right);
             else addElementNotSeen(x , curent.left);        
         }
     } 
}
```

However , my root seems to not get any value.I've seen that in Java you don't need to pass arguments by reference so I can't see the problem.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check if `node` is `null` and then create it, you are actually creating a new node for the reference of the parameter, not for the original reference that you passed outside the function.

So, instead of checking if `node` is `null` in `addElementNotSeen`, check if `this.root` is `null` in `addElement`, and instantiate **directly**.

```java
public void addElement(int x)
     {
         if(this.root == null)
            this.root = new node(x, null, null)
         else
             addElementNotSeen(x , this.root)
     }
```

The same goes when passing recursively the data down your tree. Don't risk to pass `null` as a parameter. Check if `left` or `right` are null and if so, create them directly, as in the previous example with `this.root`.

```java
     private void addElementNotSeen(int x , node curent)
     {
         else
         {
             if (x > curent.data){
                 if (curent.right == null)
                     curent.right = new node(data, null, null);
                 else
                     addElementNotSeen(x , curent.right);
             }else{
                 // the same for left
             }        
         }
     }
```

Comment: So , when I passed this.root as a parameter , the method addElementNotSeen was added to stack memory.Inside it , "curent" will be pointing at the same object as "this.root" , but are "curent" and "root" actually the same?Or they have different adresses in the memory?

Comment: `curent` will be pointing at the same object as `this.root`, right, but in the very moment you do `curent = ...`, curent will be pointing to a different thing than `this.root`, *not modifying the same object*. Think of java variables as you would with pointers in C++ (if you have experience with them). They are references, so `=` just changes the reference, not modifies the object.

Comment: I know C++ pretty well , I am learning Java to start android dev.Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
curent = new node(x , null , null);
```

doesn't have any effect outside of `addElementNotSeen` since it modifies local reference only.

See [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html):

> Reference data type parameters, such as objects, are also passed into methods by value. This means that when the method returns, the passed-in reference still references the same object as before. However, the values of the object's fields can be changed in the method, if they have the proper access level.

Comment: I still don't get it ... so how should i change it?

Comment: Consider creating new node instance in the addElement